# upper_bound on vector<pair<int,int>>

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to use `upper_bound` on a `vector<pair<int,int>>`, like this :

```
vector<pair<int,int>> data;
auto up = upper_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);
```

VS2012 gives me the following error :

```
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'const int'
```

why is it trying to compare a `const int` with a `pair<int,int>` ?

I tried writing my own comparison function, but it doesn't change anything. The compiler tries to convert a `pair<int,int>` into a `const int` if I do that.

Comment: In this call `upper_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);` the last parameter is obviously a number. Show your comparator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing a pair with a number, there is no predefined comparison operator for that. You might want to change it into something like this:

```
auto up = upper_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), make_pair(0, 0));
```

Alternatively, if there is a specific logic in your application for comparing a pair with a single number, you can provide your own comparison function:

```
bool cmp(int n, pair<int, int> const& p)
{
    // For instance...
    return ((p.first < n) && (p.second < n));
}

int main()
{
    vector<pair<int,int>> data;
    auto up = upper_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), 0, cmp);
}
```

Comment: Isn't that precisely equivalent?

Comment: haha, I've been looking for complex stuff for an hour but it never occurred to me to even look at the parameters (I just put 0 to do some test). Sorry about the question, I'm embarrassed now !

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, it is. The "For instance..." there is meant to state that it could be changed.

Answer (score 2):

> why is it trying to compare a const int with a pair ?

Because you told it to. Your comparison value is `0`, but your element type is `pair<int,int>`.

Duh doy!

Perhaps you're looking for:

```
auto up = upper_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), make_pair(0, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to `std::upper_bound` is the value that the element pointed to by the returned iterator should be greater than. How would you determine whether an `std::pair<int,int>` is greater than `0` or not?

What you pass should almost certainly be a `std::pair<int,int>`:

```
auto up = upper_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), std::make_pair(first, second));
```

However, `first` and `second` depend on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Depends. It may absolutely make sense to search for a number. In fact, I have this exact use-case (I’m searching for intervals which contain a point on a line).

Comment: @Light No, why? The sorted-array search algorithms in the standard library are **explicitly** designed with this use-case in mind (look at the documentation of the comparison function). It’s a legitimate use, and actually a pretty common one – it’s an easy and efficient way of representing a collection of ranges.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for an incompatible type you need to take special care in your comparison function. Quoting from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound):

> The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
> ```
>
> […] The type `Type1` must be such that an object of type `T` can be implicitly converted to `Type1`. The type `Type2` must be such that an object of type `ForwardIt` can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to `Type2`.​

– In your case, `Type1` = `int` and `Type2` = `std::pair<int, int>`. That should do the trick.